# AngularJS avoid multiple $resource to same URL

Tags: angularjs

I have some services to get and share data provider from server between multiple controllers and factories. When I'm loading a page some factories can call to same service function to get server data. It produces multiple HTTP calls to same API resource. I have a minimal control to save API data to a variable and forward calls use this data. I wish avoid this. Can I do one request and other data petition wait to complete the first request?

Actual implementation example:

```
function getAllCategories() {
       var deferred = $q.defer();

       if (categoriesInitialized == 1) {
           deferred.resolve(categories);
       }
       else {
           categoriesInitialized = 0;
           categoryApiMethods.getAll(function (result) {
               for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                   if (!checkCategoryExists(result[i]))
                       categories.push(new categoryModel(result[i]));
               }
               categoriesInitialized = 1;

               deferred.resolve(categories);
           }, function (data, status, header, config) {
               //toaster.pop('error', data);
               deferred.reject(data, status, header, config);
           });
       }

       return deferred.promise;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a loading value to your logic and save an array of pending promises to resolve when loading is complete.

```
function getAllCategories() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   if (!loading && categoriesInitialized == 1) {
       deferred.resolve(categories);
   }
   else if (!loading) {
       categoriesInitialized = 0;
       loading = true;
         categoryApiMethods.getAll(function (result) {
           for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
               if (!checkCategoryExists(result[i]))
                   categories.push(new categoryModel(result[i]));
           }
           categoriesInitialized = 1;
           loading = false;

           deferred.resolve(categories);
               waiting.forEach(function(promise) {
           promise.resolve(categories);
         }
       }, function (data, status, header, config) {
           //toaster.pop('error', data);
           deferred.reject(data, status, header, config);
waiting.forEach(function(promise) {
           promise.reject(....);
         }
       });
   } else {
      waiting.push(deferred.promise);
   }

   return deferred.promise;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have needed rewrite some lines of your code. I edited your solution to fix a error and put the more completed.